# Pass data from settings.gradle to build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

My project required to read json file in settings.gradle and then pass it to build.gradle file. I have tried to do it with gradle global variable 'project', but it isn't available in settings.gradle. Also, there is 'rootProject' variable in settings.gradle but it's read only.

Comment: can we read command line arguments in settings.gradle and how did u read json file in settings.gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer has been found. It's possible to pass data through global variable 'gradle'.

```
gradle.ext.configFile = inputJSON;
```